# How to see Java output (getting "java.exe" exited with code 2)?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Is there any way I can see what the error actually is in a case like this?

All I get is ""java.exe" exited with code 2"

It's hard to fix the issue if I can even see what the issue is.

Comment: Enable MSbuild diagnostic level logging.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in another thread.. took me longer than it should have:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output